# Menu Item incorrectly displays category view with list of categories and link to categories

Tags: menu-item, seo

I created a menu item with alias 'sci-fi-offer' and the full path /fiction/offers/sci-fi-offer. I changed the menu item to an url for the time being and it looked and worked all fine but I got some weird URLs in Webmaster and on further investigation found out that I could still put the url 'site.com/fiction/offers/sci-fi-offer' and instead of showing a 404 as I expected; I get a page with the list of categories as follows:

```
uncategorised(22) - (Linked to: /fiction/offers/sci-fi-offer/1-uncategorised)
sci-fi(14) - (Linked to: /fiction/offers/sci-fi-offer/3-sci-fi)
drama(12) - (Linked to: /fiction/offers/sci-fi-offer/5-darama)
autobiography(7) - (Linked to: /fiction/offers/sci-fi-offer/7-autobiography)
```

Those are all categories and the number of articles are in the brackets. The categories all have links but none of those links are correct. Could anyone point me what the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Have you create a menu item with type List All Categories. Your result will be as above if you have done that.

If you want to point to a single article then you need to choose a different menu item type. viz. single article and choose the relevant article.

Comment: Nope. The Menu Item was originally created as alias of a Single Article Menu Item but then I modified it to an external link.